# iOS Creating a file in a public folder

Tags: ios, objective-c, file, public

I want to let the user choose the folder, where I'd save a new file.

To achieve that, I use document picker, and set the document type to `public.folder` and inMode `UIDocumentPickerModeOpen`.

After user opens the document picker and selects the desired folder, in `didPickDocumentsAtURLs` callback I get the NSUrl object, which has permissions to modify the file at that url (in this case, it's an url to a folder).

There is my issue. I have the url with access permission to a folder, however, to create a file I ussualy need to have the filename.extension in the url. If I were to modify the NSUrl object I've received from the document picker, or convert it to NSString, my guess is I lose the access permission and `createFileAtPath` method always fails.

What method do I need to use, or what configuration document picker do I need, in order to create a new file in the path that the user selected? I attach my current code:

```
- (void)openDocumentPicker:(NSString*)pickerType
{
    //Find the current app window, and its view controller object
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIWindow* rootWindow = app.windows[0];
    UIViewController* rootViewController = rootWindow.rootViewController;
    
    //Initialize the document picker
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[pickerType] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];

    //Assigning the delegate, connects the document picker object with callbacks, defined in this object
    documentPicker.delegate = self;

    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    //Call the document picker, to the view controller that we've found before
    [rootViewController presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}


- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentsAtURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)urls
{
    //If we come here, user successfully picked a file/folder

    [urls[0] startAccessingSecurityScopedResource]; //Let the os know we're going to use the file
        
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

    NSString *documentsDirectory = urls[0].absoluteString;

    NSString *newFilePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"test.txt"];
    NSError *error = nil;
        
    if ([fileManager createFileAtPath:newFilePath contents:[@"new file test" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] attributes:nil]){
        NSLog(@"Create Sucess");
    }
    else{
        NSLog(@"Create error: %@", error);
    }

    [urls[0] stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource]; //Let the os know we're done
}
```

Any leads would be kindly appreciated!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I'll leave a fully working code bellow.

My main issue was, that when you're using "public.folder" document type, you need to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` with the url of the chosen folder, not with the modified link (file the user chose + NewFileName.extension)

```
- (void)openDocumentPicker
{
    //This is needed, when using this code on QT!
    //Find the current app window, and its view controller object
    /*
    UIApplication* app = [UIApplication sharedApplication];
    UIWindow* rootWindow = app.windows[0];
    UIViewController* rootViewController = rootWindow.rootViewController;
    */

    //Initialize the document picker. Set appropriate document types
    //When reading: use document type of the file, that you're going to read
    //When writing into a new file: use @"public.folder" to select a folder, where your new file will be created
    UIDocumentPickerViewController *documentPicker = [[UIDocumentPickerViewController alloc] initWithDocumentTypes:@[@"public.folder"] inMode:UIDocumentPickerModeOpen];

    //Assigning the delegate, connects the document picker object with callbacks, defined in this object
    documentPicker.delegate = self;

    documentPicker.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    //In this case we're using self. If using on QT, use the rootViewController we've found before
    [self presentViewController:documentPicker animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)documentPicker:(UIDocumentPickerViewController *)controller didPickDocumentsAtURLs:(NSArray<NSURL *> *)urls
{
    //If we come here, user successfully picked a single file/folder

    //When selecting a folder, we need to start accessing the folder itself, instead of the specific file we're going to create
    if ( [urls[0] startAccessingSecurityScopedResource] ) //Let the os know we're going use this resource
    {
        //Write file case ---
    
        //Construct the url, that we're going to be using: folder the user chose + add the new FileName.extension
        NSURL *destURLPath = [urls[0] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Test.txt"];
    
        NSString *dataToWrite = @"This text is going into the file!";
    
        NSError *error = nil;
    
        //Write the data, thus creating a new file. Save the new path if operation succeeds
        if( ![dataToWrite writeToURL:destURLPath atomically:true encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error] )
            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);

    
        //Read file case ---
        NSData *fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:destURLPath options:NSDataReadingUncached error:&error];
    
        if( fileData == nil )
            NSLog(@"%@",[error localizedDescription]);
    
        [urls[0] stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource];
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"startAccessingSecurityScopedResource failed");
    }
}
```

This was also being discussed at apple forums:

Thread name: "iOS Creating a file in a public folder"

Thread link:
https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/685170?answerId=682427022#682427022

Answer (score 0):

This is solution in swift, please try and let me knwo if any problem

```
func documentPicker(_ controller: UIDocumentPickerViewController, didPickDocumentsAt urls: [URL]){
    
    var imgData: Data?
    if let url = urls.first{
        imgData = try? Data(contentsOf: url)
        do{
            let documentDirectory = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true)[0] as NSString
            let destURLPath = documentDirectory.appendingPathComponent(url.lastPathComponent)
            try imgData?.write(to: URL(fileURLWithPath: destURLPath))
            print("FILES IS Writtern at DOcument Directory")
        }catch{
            
        }
        
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your answer!
I'm having some trouble using your code. I've successfully translated it to objective-c (also tested on a swift project), destURLPath I get on both languages is: "/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/A788FED2-B5C9-4E39-BC9F-A4052D2F31F5/Documents/File%20Provider%20Storage".

When I try to write to the url using NSData writeToURL, it fails.
I've also tried to modify the url to add a file name "/test.txt" and use NSFileManager createFileAtPath, that also fails.

How do I need to use your code, to create a file, that I could write data in?

Comment: can you make swift helper class to use same code?

Comment: Did you mean to ask, if I could use swift code in my original project? Because I don't think so, since I'm actually implementing objective-c code in a c++ project.

However, if you'll provide me with a complete example in swift code, maybe I'd be able to translate it to objective-c!

Comment: i have given you full delegate method, this will work fine

Comment: The thing is, even if I try to run your code in swift by itself, it runs successfully, however no file gets created. Do I need to add any additional code, to create a file?

Comment: catch{
          print(error)  
        }  try this is you get any error in try catch